# Evernote node sdk, not able to authenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, evernote

I try to authenticate a evernote user with node js, everything works fine until the callback url is called, then i get an error with the status code 400

My code:

```
app.get('/api/auth/authenticate', function(req, res){

    var client = new Evernote.Client({
        consumerKey: evernoteConfig.EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_KEY,
        consumerSecret: evernoteConfig.EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        sandbox: true 
    });

    client.getRequestToken(evernoteConfig.callbackURL, function(error, 
        oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret, results){

         if(error) {
      req.session.error = JSON.stringify(error);
      res.json("Shit:"+req.session.error);
    }
    else { 
      // store the tokens in the session
      req.session.oauthToken = oauthToken;
      req.session.oauthTokenSecret = oauthTokenSecret;

      // redirect the user to authorize the token
      res.redirect(client.getAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken));
    }
    });

});

 app.get('/api/auth/evernote/callback', function(req, res){
    var client = new Evernote.Client({
  consumerKey: evernoteConfig.API_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumerSecret: evernoteConfig.API_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  sandbox: true
});

client.getAccessToken(
  req.session.oauthToken, 
  req.session.oauthTokenSecret, 
  req.param('oauth_verifier'), 
  function(error, oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, results) {
    if(error) {
      res.json("Error:"+JSON.stringify(error));
    } else {
    // store the access token in the session
      req.session.oauthAccessToken = oauthAccessToken;
      req.session.oauthAccessTtokenSecret = oauthAccessTokenSecret;
      req.session.edamShard = results.edam_shard;
      req.session.edamUserId = results.edam_userId;
      req.session.edamExpires = results.edam_expires;
      req.session.edamNoteStoreUrl = results.edam_noteStoreUrl;
      req.session.edamWebApiUrlPrefix = results.edam_webApiUrlPrefix;
      res.json("Success");
    }
 });
});
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong... Maybe someone of you has some more experience with the evernote js sdk

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your OAuth Verifier and make sure that is correct.  I wrote a (relatively untested) regrex for to properly grab the OAuth verifier.  My (working) code is otherwise very similar:

```
function getOauthVerifier(url) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]oauth_verifier=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

...

```
  else if (pathname == "/oauth"){
    client.getAccessToken(
      global.oauthToken, 
      global.oauthSecret, 
      getOauthVerifier(params.search), 
      function(error, oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, results) {
        if(error) {
          console.log("error\n\n\n");
          console.log(error);
        }
        else {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
          response.write(oauthAccessToken);
          response.end();
        }   
      }
    );
  }
  else {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.write("not a valid URL <a href=\"/\"> GO HOME </a>");
    response.end();
  }
```

Full Example:https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/80668-oauth-does-not-work-in-js/#entry341806